When can I put a starter lemon tree outside overnight?
I have a healthy lemon tree I’ve grown indoors from seed it’s out grown the windowsill I’ve been putting out during the day but in at night what’s too cold for an evening out?

What hardiness zone/where are you?

Google quotes

between 68°F and 82.4°F (20°C and 28°C)

from here.
So - if possible - in the wee hours of the night - go out and check a thermometer(don't go out with one - it needs time to stabilize). But if You don't happen to wake up after midnight and don't have a 24/7 camera, check the weather forecast's "low".
